# Print output of subprocess.run AND display it on screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to run a shell command via `subprocess.run`, and I would like to redirect the output to a file, but also display it on stdout at the same time.

I have not found a way to do it, is this possible in a pure Python script?

It would be equivalent to doing `some_command | tee file.txt` in bash.

I could always write a wrapper bash script that will invoke the python script and call tee, but would be nice if Python had a way to do this directly.

Comment: Have you considered using 'subprocess.Popen()', and than 'subprocess.Communicate()'?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I didn't find that.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the output and send to stdout and a file.

Python 3.7+:

```
r = subprocess.run(cmds, capture_output=True, text=True)
```

Python 3.5+:

```
r = subprocess.run(cmds, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout = r.stdout.decode("utf-8") # specify encoding
```

Example

```
import subprocess
r = subprocess.run(['ls'], capture_output=True, text=True)
print(r.stdout)
with open('a.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(r.stdout)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I want to print the lines out while the command is running and producing output.